# Is it is possible to do something when the Java program exits abruptly?

Tags: java

I need to record an log if the program exited abruptly or with any exception. For example, when someone presses `Ctrl+C` while running program, I need to log that it exited abruptly. How can I do this?

Answer (score 12):

You can try and use a [shutdown hook](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook(java.lang.Thread)) for this. From the documentation, the hook will be executed under the following circumstances:

- The program exits normally
- The VM is terminated

This covers your `^C` situation, but will doubtfully cover situations like the machine being unplugged (barring some sort of redundant hardware on the machine).

[Here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html) are some notes about the design.

Crude example:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("System was shutdown");
    }
});
```

Comment: I think it will run on CTRL+C and `SIGTERM` but I think there are other ways to kill the program where this wont run

Comment: I've seen embedded systems that could actually log a power loss event.  Need a pretty big capacitor and a pretty small interrupt service routine, but it can be done.

Comment: Another alternative is to log successful shutdowns and check on startup that the last run of the program was successfully shut down.